# Product view and search result on the same

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, search

If I use the navigation menu to arrive at a product "detail" page then it all shows up nicely. But if I use the search to arrive at a product "detail" page then the picture and title show up but no pricing or description show up. This, I now know, has to do with the search view not providing a category ID.

Here it is when you use the search feature to arrive at the page.
[image: Testing this feature]
Here it is when you use the regular navigation to arrive at the page.
[image]
Here is the error message that I get on that page when I turn on error reporting
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /../../public_html/store/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml on line 38

The code throwing the error is

$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

on line 38 but I don't understand how to fix it so the code responds on search and product pages.

```
<!-- Stock Status -->
<div class="stock status">
<?php 
    $manageStock = $_product->getStockItem()->getManageStock();

    $inventoryQuantity = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $curID = $currentCategory->getId();

    $one = 71;
    $two = 8;
    $three = 4;
    if ($manageStock == 1) // If 'Manage Stock' is set to YES
        {
        // If 'Qty' is less than or equal to zero
        /*if(($inventoryQuantity <= 0) && ($curID == $one || $curID == $two || $curID == $three)) { ?> */
        if(($inventoryQuantity <= 0) && (in_array($curID, array($one, $two, $three)))) { ?> 
            <div class="availability in-stock">
                <span>
                <?php echo $this->__('Availability dependent on shipping method.'); ?>
                </span> 
            </div>
        <?php } 
        // If 'Qty' is less than or equal to zero
        if(($inventoryQuantity <= 0) && ($curID != $one && $curID != $two && $curID != $three)) { ?> 
            <div class="availability out-of-stock">
                <span>
                    <?php echo $this->__('Out of Stock'); ?>
                    <?php echo $curID; ?>
                </span> 
            </div>
        <?php }
        else if($inventoryQuantity > 0) { ?> 
            <div class="availability in-stock">
                <span>
                    <?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?><?php echo $this->__(' In Stock'); ?>
                </span>
            </div> 
        <?php } 
        }
    ?>
    </div>
<!-- // Stock Status -->
```

Any thoughts? It's been driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in a search result context there is no category.
So this code `$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');` returns `null`  and later you try to call a method on a null  variable `$curID = $currentCategory->getId();`.
PHP does not agree with this.

On a separate topic this is wrong for so many reasons:

```
if(($inventoryQuantity <= 0) && ($curID == $one || $curID == $two || $curID == $three)) { ?> 
   <div class="availability in-stock">
```

First if all you are hard-coding some category ids.
Second, you have a long condition that looks ugly.

```
($curID == $one || $curID == $two || $curID == $three)
```

can simply be written as

```
(in_array($curID, array($one, $two, $three)))
```

Third...I can't seam to understand the logic of the code.. 
So you are displaying the availability only if the inventory qty is 0 or below and the current category is one of the 3 listed above?

Comment: Yeah it's rough, I agree. The logic is that I'm displaying a custom availability message for products that are on back order (not really actually back ordered because it's a drop ship service) and only in a certain couple categories.

Comment: Any thoughts then on how to make this whole thing work properly?

Comment: Instead of checking the current category id, get the category ids from the product with `$_product->getCategoryIds()`. Then see if one of the ids matches your ids.

Comment: ok cool, I can see how that would help. This leaves me trying to figure out how to grab the "last" categoryID though because I'm only referring to the lowest category level and $curID = $_product->getCategoryIds(); doesn't return an int.

Could you help me format that statement properly?

$_product->getCategoryIds();
 $curID = "last category ID code"

Answer (score 1):

I was just writing my answer but Marius got there first.

But, I'll just piggyback on his answer:

Search for: `Mage::register('current_category'` to see where the code in your base tries to set current_category. Ideally, templates on product page shouldn't expect current_category to exist in the registry but I guess you have some customization to your code. That search I mentioned would help.